# How can I simplify this redundant C++ code?

Tags: c++

There are two existing classes, one is `SrcField` which returns the concrete type value, and the other is a union `DSTField`, that defines the corresponding data type.

```
class SrcField
{
public:
    signed char     GetInt8();
    unsigned char   GetUInt8();
    short           GetInt16();
    unsigned short  GetUInt16();
    int             GetInt32();
    unsigned int    GetUInt32();
    float           GetFloat();
    double          GetDouble();
    bool            GetBool();
    DataType        GetType();
private:
    DataType m_type;
    DSTField m_data;
};

union DSTField
{
    signed char    m_int8;
    unsigned char  m_uint8;
    short          m_int16;
    unsigned short m_uint16;
    int            m_int32;
    unsigned int   m_uint32;
    float          m_float;
    double         m_double;
    bool           m_bool;
};
```

When I use both classes, the application is as below.
It's very redundant; is there any good way to simplify it, such as templates, generic programming, etc?

```
int main()
{
    SrcField sf;
    DSTField df;

    switch(sf.GetType())
    {
    case TYPE_INT8:
        df.m_int8 = sf.GetInt8();
        break;
    case TYPE_UINT8:
        df.m_uint8 = sf.GetUInt8();
        break;
    case TYPE_INT16:
        df.m_int16 = sf.GetInt16();
        break;
    case TYPE_UINT16:
        df.m_uint16 = sf.GetUInt16();
        break;
    case TYPE_INT32:
        df.m_int32 = sf.GetInt32();
        break;
    case TYPE_UINT32:
        df.m_uint32 = sf.GetUInt32();
        break;
    case TYPE_FLOAT:
        df.m_float = sf.GetFloat();
        break;
    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
        df.m_double = sf.GetDouble();
        break;
    case TYPE_BOOL:
        df.m_bool = sf.GetBool();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `boost::variant` or `std::variant`?

Comment: Why do you use getters?

Comment: ..or `boost::any` (though I prefer `variant` too if the set of types is restricted.

Comment: you can use `std::variant`, or something like an union with your two fields, but by seeing your code I suggest you to review it and maybe perform a refactoring; maybe these two classes are not the best solution...

Comment: @NickyC Not familiar with it, I will check it.

Comment: both the class is exsiting class ( you can think it's the 3rd party), I have no choice.   I just  take it simple example,  in fact, we need get the value from srcfield instance and save it.  @Nim

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @freshyy How are you saving it? What's the interface?

Depending on how much freedom you have for choosing the interface, the solution will be different. But you probably can't avoid some form of switch.

Comment: Sorry, "saving" just means generic assignment, no other special things.

Comment: Just wrap the horribleness in a convenience function and forget about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `std::variant` your code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<
    signed char,
    unsigned char,
    short,
    unsigned short,
    int,
    unsigned int,
    float,
    double,
    bool
> SrcField, DSTField;

int main()
{
    SrcField sf(97.0f);
    DSTField df;

    df = sf;

    if(auto pval = std::get_if<float>(&df))
      std::cout << "variant value: " << *pval << '\n'; 
    else 
      std::cout << "failed to get value!" << '\n';
}
```

---

Note: Since it's c++17, for previous versions I recommend to use `boost::variant`, `boost::any` or a header-only implementation of `Any` class (for example I use one based on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/c11-any-class) in my project)

Comment: `std::variant` is part of the new C++17 standard. So use these capabilities of boost.

Comment: Thanks for your code. But it seem like you have redefined the legacy class, in fact, which is the 3rd part exported class, I can NOT change it. If so, does it mean switch-case statement can NOT be avoided?

Comment: @freshyy Yes, I've read your comment about it later. If you cannot change the definitions, you are restricted to do what API allows. It seems to provide you only type getters, so I'm afraid using those in a switch statement is all you can do.

Comment: Any and Variant are very different types

Answer (score 2):

You said that you cannot change `SrcField`, therefore a good solution could be the use of a visitor. The redundant code is still there, but it is present only once. See this:

```
template<typename Visitor>
constexpr void
visitField(Visitor&& visitor, SrcField& field)
{
    switch(field.GetType())
    {
    case TYPE_INT8:
        visitor(field.GetInt8());
        break;
    case TYPE_UINT8:
        visitor(field.GetUInt8());
        break;
    ....
    default:
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid type");
}
```

In this way you are able to use the values in a simple way:

```
int main()
{
    SrcField field;
    visitField([](auto value) {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<decltype(value), double>::value)
            std::cout << "Hey, double here!\n";
        else if constexpr(std::is_same<decltype(value), bool>::value)
            std::cout << "True or false?\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Other types\n";
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }, field);
}
```

In this case I used the `if constexpr` capability from C++17. Another possibility use a [*lambda overload*](http://martinecker.com/martincodes/lambda-expression-overloading/)

You can find a more complete example [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/wzjTm6)

**Note:** As you can see, I **did not use** `DSTField` at all. If you really need to use `DSTField`, you can use a similar approach:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void
setField(DSTField& dstField, T value)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
                  "value must be an arithmetic type");

    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, signed char>::value)
        dstField.m_int8 = value;
    else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value)
        dstField.m_uint8 = value;
    ...
}
```

which can be used with something like

```
DSTField dest;
setField(dest, 4.f);
```

**Other note:** I marked the `visitField` function as *constexpr*, but I cannot be sure if you can use in that way. Indeed, if `SrcField::GetType` can only be executed at *runtime*, `visitField` will never be executed at *compile time*.

**Other other note:** I don't know if this could depend on your code or not, but you have to keep in mind that you **cannot** be sure that `signed char` is a `std::int8_t` (as for most of the other types, obviously). You should use *fixed width integer types* if you want to make your code work as expected on foreign architectures.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed sample codes and kindly suggestions. But I have to explain my usage context:
1.  I MUST get the value from SrcField to assign to the DSTField field, which is one mandatory object as parameter transmit to next function call.
2.  Due to #1,  as you suggested,  I have to write the codes  *setField* and *visitField*.   This might have become a little overkill, because in fact, I just write once to do get-set task,  so the amount of source codes seem not less than mine.

in my first test,  I used macro to simplify, but it's not easy to trobuleshooting in future.

Comment: @freshyy True indeed: if you just need to do this __once__, the only two things that could help you are macros and maybe, in the future, reflection. And as you said, it is better to be careful with macros ;)